# Make sets from array, which contains array of custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
NSMutableArray *arrayDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CustomClass *country1       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country1.strCountryName     =  @"USA";
country1.code               =  @"12";
[arrayDetails addObject:country1];

CustomClass *country2       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country2.strCountryName     =  @"India";
country2.code               =  @"234";
[arrayDetails addObject:country2];

CustomClass *country4       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country4.strCountryName     =  @"UK";
country4.code               =   @"34";
[arrayDetails addObject:country4];

CustomClass *country5       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country5.strCountryName     =  @"USA";
country5.code               =  @"12";
[arrayDetails addObject:country5];

CustomClass *country6       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country6.strCountryName     =  @"India";
country6.code               =  @"12";
[arrayDetails addObject:country6];

CustomClass *country7       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country7.strCountryName     =  @"India";
country7.code               =  @"12";
[arrayDetails addObject:country7];

CustomClass *country8       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country8.strCountryName     =  @"USA";
country8.code               =  @"12";
[arrayDetails addObject:country8];

CustomClass *country3       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country3.strCountryName     =  @"UK";
country3.code               =  @"12";
[arrayDetails addObject:country3];


CustomClass *country77       = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
country77.strCountryName     =  @"PAK";
country77.code               =  @"12";
[arrayDetails addObject:country3];
```

I want to make **separate sets based on country name**, all custom class objects which contain the USA in one array, India in the array and UK one array, even single object PAK. 
Data comes from the server, based on the strContry name I want to make groups.

Comment: what is here custom class...?

Comment: just a model class

Comment: you have to use NSPredicate to differentiate after matching fields from  custom class. Still i dont have the code. But this should be the way

Answer (score 0):

After adding all objects to "arraydetails", try the below code for achieving the same.

```
NSArray *countryNames = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:[arrayDetails valueForKey:@"strCountryName"]] array];
    for (int i =0; i < [countryNames count]; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *countryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (CustomClass *country in arrayDetails) {
            if ([country.strCountryName isEqualToString:[countryNames objectAtIndex:i]]) {
                [countryArray addObject:country];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Country array[%d] is %@", i, countryArray);
    }
```